# WPF render translation worsens image quality

Tags: c#, wpf, rendertransform

I have `Image` with some text and icons, where source was rendered from `UserControl` like this:

```
control.Measure(new Size(300, 300));
control.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(300,300)));

RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(300, 300, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

bmp.Render(control);

ImageSource source = BitmapFrame.Create(bmp);
```

It is to be expected to lose quality when scaling/rotating non-vector images, especially if there some text involved. Problem is that it also happens with translation. It doesn't matter if i translate Image itself or its parent container. What's strange is that quality worsens seemenly equally with rotation and translation. What's very strange is that the quality only degrades with horizontal translation, not vertical translation. Is there something can be done about this?

P.S.
Only reason that i need do render `UserControl` is text with icons inside (`InlineContainers`). If there is a way to convert and put it inside certain bounds as group of `Drawings` without manually calculating each block's position, it would be nice.

Comment: Have you tried to set SnapsToDevicePixels on the Image element?

Comment: You mean inlineuicontainer? Can't you use a viewbox to scale it initially and then rotate? Otherwise, you can convert text to a path or paths so you could work with vectors. Scale the parent so you don't have to recalculate positions. Difficult to say if that'd be a good idea without more info.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, but there is no perceivable difference for me.

Comment: @Andy Images are transformed at runtime (slightly animated), so initial transformation wouldnt help much. I can convert plain text to path, but i need to do it inside given bounds with some images in between. `TextBlock` manages to do it automaticly, obviously. Although, i probably can make some frankenstein by placing `TextBlock` on top of a simple vector image inside some container. Not sure if that is a good idea, but i think it certainly better than using whole `UserControl`.